# How to concat pandas dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of python objects which are some how like this

```
team_1_players1=[] is a list
```

**inside team_1_players1=[] there are multiple json objects stored.**

1st Json Object like this

```
[[{'age_days': '72', 'age_years': '30', 'alpha_name': 'RAVAL,JA', 'batting_hand': 'left-hand batsman', 'batting_style': 'lhb', 'batting_style_long': 'left-hand bat', 'bowling_hand': 'right-arm bowler', 'bowling_pacespin': 'spin bowler', 'bowling_style': 'lb', 'bowling_style_long': 'legbreak ', 'captain': '0', 'card_long': 'JA Raval', 'card_qualifier': '', 'card_short': 'Raval', 'dob': '1988-09-22', 'keeper': '0', 'known_as': 'Jeet Raval', 'mobile_name': 'Raval', 'object_id': '277914', 'player_id': '51094', 'player_primary_role': 'opening batsman', 'player_style_id': '1', 'player_type': '1', 'player_type_name': 'player', 'popular_name': 'Raval', 'portrait_alt_id': '1', 'portrait_object_id': '397349', 'status_id': '3'}, {'age_days': '245', 'age_years': '26', 'alpha_name': 'LATHAM,TWM', 'batting_hand': 'left-hand batsman', 'batting_style': 'lhb', 'batting_style_long': 'left-hand bat', 'bowling_hand': 'right-arm bowler', 'bowling_pacespin': 'pace bowler', 'bowling_style': 'rm', 'bowling_style_long': 'right-arm medium ', 'captain': '0', 'card_long': 'TWM Latham', 'card_qualifier': '', 'card_short': 'Latham', 'dob': '1992-04-02', 'keeper': '0', 'known_as': 'Tom Latham', 'mobile_name': 'Latham', 'object_id': '388802', 'player_id': '59148', 'player_primary_role': 'wicketkeeper batsman', 'player_style_id': '7', 'player_type': '1', 'player_type_name': 'player', 'popular_name': 'Latham', 'portrait_alt_id': '1', 'portrait_object_id': '1099471', 'status_id': '3'}]]
```

when I am trying to store in the dataframe i am getting like this

```
0{'age_days': '72', 'age_years': '30', 'alpha_n...}   
1   {'age_days': '196', 'age_years': '23', 'alpha_...} 
2   {'age_days': '99', 'age_years': '29', 'alpha_n...}
```

2nd Json Object is like this

```
[[{'age_days': '123', 'age_years': '25', 'alpha_name': 'LIVINGSTONE,LS', 'batting_hand': 'right-hand batsman', 'batting_style': 'rhb', 'batting_style_long': 'right-hand bat', 'bowling_hand': 'right-arm bowler', 'bowling_pacespin': 'spin bowler', 'bowling_style': 'lb', 'bowling_style_long': 'legbreak ', 'captain': '0', 'card_long': 'LS Livingstone', 'card_qualifier': '', 'card_short': 'Livingstone', 'dob': '1993-08-04', 'keeper': '0', 'known_as': 'Liam Livingstone', 'mobile_name': '', 'object_id': '403902', 'player_id': '59832', 'player_primary_role': None, 'player_style_id': None, 'player_type': '1', 'player_type_name': 'player', 'popular_name': '', 'portrait_alt_id': '1', 'portrait_object_id': '863825', 'status_id': '3'}, {'age_days': '142', 'age_years': '23', 'alpha_name': 'HAIN,SR', 'batting_hand': 'right-hand batsman', 'batting_style': 'rhb', 'batting_style_long': 'right-hand bat', 'bowling_hand': 'right-arm bowler', 'bowling_pacespin': 'spin bowler', 'bowling_style': 'ob', 'bowling_style_long': 'right-arm offbreak ', 'captain': '0', 'card_long': 'SR Hain', 'card_qualifier': '', 'card_short': 'Hain', 'dob': '1995-07-16', 'keeper': '0', 'known_as': 'Sam Hain', 'mobile_name': 'Hain', 'object_id': '555850', 'player_id': '67482', 'player_primary_role': None, 'player_style_id': None, 'player_type': '1', 'player_type_name': 'player', 'popular_name': 'Hain', 'portrait_alt_id': '1', 'portrait_object_id': '631902', 'status_id': '3'}]]
```

I want to store all the json objects into the dataframe
**this is the code of appending json objects into the list**

```
team_1_players1=[]
for x in matchList:
    m=MyMatch(x)
    team_1_players1.append(m.team_1_players)
```

this is how i am converting the team_1_players1 list into dataframe

```
for i in range(team_1_players1):
    df = pd.DataFrame(team_1_players1[i])
```

When i am only using this line without loop

```
df = pd.DataFrame(team_1_players1[0])
```

I am getting the dataframe like this

[image]

When I am printing the second index like this I am getting results

```
df = pd.DataFrame(team_1_players1[1])
```

[image]

**Now i want to combine all the results**

**that is why i have used the for loop to iterate through all the dataframe**

```
for i in range(team_1_players1):
    df = pd.DataFrame(team_1_players1[i])
```

**I have more than 1000 json objects which are stored inside the team_1_players1 list so is there any efficient way**

Comment: what's `MyMatch`? is it a call to a class constructor?

Comment: there is nothing problem with the class i am getting the json results from the class  which is 100% correct

Comment: I though json objects are in the list `team_1_players1`. So I don't understand what `MyMatch` is. Your code cannot be reproduced because we don't have this function/class

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki team_1_players1 is a list which has all the json values

Comment: in your loop you are creating the DataFrame at each iteration. Instead concatenate all your lists into a list of lists, then outside the loop just create a DataFrame. This will be way more efficients than using `concat` inside the loop

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I am sharing the json inside the questions please review and make an answer if you could. the json is stored in team_1_players1 list

Comment: use [pd.read_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html) to convert your json files into DataFrames.

Comment: So you want a dataframe with one column where the value is the json object?

Comment: I want to store the json column values into different dataframe values

Comment: @DanielMesejo I have explained the question in the very brief manner

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki have you understand it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, flatten your nested list:

```
import itertools as it 

data = list(it.chain.from_iterable(team_1_players1))
```

Then use `pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
```

Comment: I have more than 1000 json objects inside the List will I use like this?

Comment: Ok, your data is structured like this: [[{...}, {...},...]], or like this: [[{...}, {...},...], [{...}, {...},...],...]?

Comment: your answer is correct post an answer so that i can accept it

Comment: so you need just unpack it to get simple list of jsons instead of passing list of list. I would use pd.DataFrame.from_records(data[0]), and looks it works well.

Comment: Sorry for long waiting. It's my first day here.

Comment: use import itertools as it
data = list(it.chain.from_iterable(team_1_players1)) in your answer

Comment: oh, that actually helped? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may try below code. I assumed all your `json` objects for team1 as `a` and second `json` as `b`

```
a = [[{'age_days': '72', 'age_years': '30', 'alpha_name': 'RAVAL,JA', 'batting_hand': 'left-hand batsman', 'batting_style': 'lhb', 'batting_style_long': 'left-hand bat', 'bowling_hand': 'right-arm bowler', 'bowling_pacespin': 'spin bowler', 'bowling_style': 'lb', 'bowling_style_long': 'legbreak ', 'captain': '0', 'card_long': 'JA Raval', 'card_qualifier': '', 'card_short': 'Raval', 'dob': '1988-09-22', 'keeper': '0', 'known_as': 'Jeet Raval', 'mobile_name': 'Raval', 'object_id': '277914', 'player_id': '51094', 'player_primary_role': 'opening batsman', 'player_style_id': '1', 'player_type': '1', 'player_type_name': 'player', 'popular_name': 'Raval', 'portrait_alt_id': '1', 'portrait_object_id': '397349', 'status_id': '3'}, {'age_days': '245', 'age_years': '26', 'alpha_name': 'LATHAM,TWM', 'batting_hand': 'left-hand batsman', 'batting_style': 'lhb', 'batting_style_long': 'left-hand bat', 'bowling_hand': 'right-arm bowler', 'bowling_pacespin': 'pace bowler', 'bowling_style': 'rm', 'bowling_style_long': 'right-arm medium ', 'captain': '0', 'card_long': 'TWM Latham', 'card_qualifier': '', 'card_short': 'Latham', 'dob': '1992-04-02', 'keeper': '0', 'known_as': 'Tom Latham', 'mobile_name': 'Latham', 'object_id': '388802', 'player_id': '59148', 'player_primary_role': 'wicketkeeper batsman', 'player_style_id': '7', 'player_type': '1', 'player_type_name': 'player', 'popular_name': 'Latham', 'portrait_alt_id': '1', 'portrait_object_id': '1099471', 'status_id': '3'}]]
b = [[{'age_days': '123', 'age_years': '25', 'alpha_name': 'LIVINGSTONE,LS', 'batting_hand': 'right-hand batsman', 'batting_style': 'rhb', 'batting_style_long': 'right-hand bat', 'bowling_hand': 'right-arm bowler', 'bowling_pacespin': 'spin bowler', 'bowling_style': 'lb', 'bowling_style_long': 'legbreak ', 'captain': '0', 'card_long': 'LS Livingstone', 'card_qualifier': '', 'card_short': 'Livingstone', 'dob': '1993-08-04', 'keeper': '0', 'known_as': 'Liam Livingstone', 'mobile_name': '', 'object_id': '403902', 'player_id': '59832', 'player_primary_role': None, 'player_style_id': None, 'player_type': '1', 'player_type_name': 'player', 'popular_name': '', 'portrait_alt_id': '1', 'portrait_object_id': '863825', 'status_id': '3'}, {'age_days': '142', 'age_years': '23', 'alpha_name': 'HAIN,SR', 'batting_hand': 'right-hand batsman', 'batting_style': 'rhb', 'batting_style_long': 'right-hand bat', 'bowling_hand': 'right-arm bowler', 'bowling_pacespin': 'spin bowler', 'bowling_style': 'ob', 'bowling_style_long': 'right-arm offbreak ', 'captain': '0', 'card_long': 'SR Hain', 'card_qualifier': '', 'card_short': 'Hain', 'dob': '1995-07-16', 'keeper': '0', 'known_as': 'Sam Hain', 'mobile_name': 'Hain', 'object_id': '555850', 'player_id': '67482', 'player_primary_role': None, 'player_style_id': None, 'player_type': '1', 'player_type_name': 'player', 'popular_name': 'Hain', 'portrait_alt_id': '1', 'portrait_object_id': '631902', 'status_id': '3'}]]

if len (a)==1 and len(b) ==1: # this checks if objects are single entity of players or multiple teams.

    team_1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a[0])
    team_2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(b[0])
    merged_team = pd.concat([df,df1], ignore_index=True)

merged_team
```

You will get output as below :-

[image]

Hope this helps.